# django-wkhtmltopdf with AJAX requests will get 403 Forbidden

Tags: ajax, django, wkhtmltopdf, django-wkhtmltopdf

**Description**

I want to generate a PDF file from Django view, so I'm using `django-wkhtmltopdf` app, the app is working but my template (that is used in the view) has many AJAX requests using jQuery. Views that requested by AJAX requests are protected by csrf token.

**Issue**

All AJAX requests are getting `403 Forbidden` response because of  CSRF verification failed.

**Trial**

I tried `django-cors-headers` and still getting the same responses.